# Zend Models Model_DbTable_Articles working, Articles not

Tags: zend-framework, model, zend-db, zend-db-table

I got problems with my ZF Models.

Where I create new model, put it in Dbtable/Articles.php and name class as Model_DbTable_Articles it is working. But when I name class Articles I got error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Articles' not found
```

Why? :)

Answer (score 0):

I put this in my bootstrap.php file

```
$autoloader = $application->getAutoloader();
$resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
    'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH,
    'namespace' => '',
    'resourceTypes' => array(
        'form' => array(
            'path' => '/forms/',
            'namespace' => 'Form_',
        ),
        'model' => array(
            'path' => '/models/',
            'namespace' => 'Model_'
        ),
        'table' => array(
            'path' => '/tables/',
            'namespace' => 'Table_'
        ),
    ),
));
```